# Array values changing by themselves in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

In the following program, I am reading a 6-length string dd and storing its ascii code in an integer array ipc of size 3x2. The problem is that the values stored in ipc are wrong and they change themselves later when I reprint them. I am surprised how can there be such a clear problem with such a simple code. (I am using Code::Blocks 10.05 on Win7 x64)

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ char dd[5];
  int ipc[2][1];
  cin.get(dd,6);
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  { for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    { ipc[i][j]=int(dd[j+2*i]);
      cout<<ipc[i][j]<<endl;
    }
  }
  cout<<"------"<<endl;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  { for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    { cout<<ipc[i][j]<<endl; }
  }
}
```

If input given is 123456, the output is:

```
49
50
51
52
53
2
------
49
51
51
53
53
2
```

Any sort of help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The array declaration is incorrect and the code is going out-of-bounds on the array causing undefined behaviour. Declaration should be changed from:

```
int ipc[2][1];
```

to:

```
int ipc[3][2];
```

Additionally, [`cin.get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) will read `count - 1` characters, so:

```
cin.get(dd, 6);
```

will only read `5` characters, not `6`. If the user enters `123456` only `12345` will be read. The `cin.get()` will also append a null character, (as commented by [tinman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583044/tinman)). To correct increase the size of `dd` and the number of characters to be read:

```
char buf[7];
cin.get(buf, 7);
```

Comment: don't arrays begin from 0, so why do I need to define ipc[3][2]?

Comment: Isn't there also an issue with `char dd[5];` and `cin.get(dd, 6);`? The '\0' will automatically be stored at dd[5].

Comment: @xan99 The indices of arrays begin counting at 0 but the size (that you are specifying here) is not an index.

Comment: When declaring arrays you specify the size not the last index.

Comment: @xan99, array _indexes_ run from `0` to `N - 1`. When specifying the dimensions you to provide the actual number, not one less.

Comment: @tinman, I think you are correct. I am currently reading ref guide for `istream.get()`...

Comment: and changing that is still showing incorrect value for last character

Comment: The indexes begin at zero so the Max indexes are 2 and 1. But the sizes are... sizes. So you create the array with sizes 3 and 2.

Comment: @hmjd, thanks for detailed explanation
also thanks to all others who helped